# LINQ Query if condition external parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use LINQ to get a list of values.

I have code like this:

```
var _context = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<VMContext>();

if (boolparameter)
{
    var listCE = _context.Ce
                         .Where(x => x.VuId == element.VuId)
                         .Where(x => x.Score == 8)
                         .AsNoTracking()
                         .ToList();
}
else
{
    var listCE = _context.Ce
                         .Where(x => x.VuId == element.VuId)
                         .AsNoTracking()
                         .ToList();
}
```

Depends on boolparameter, I do a query or another one. Is there a way to use a single query with a conditions inside?
Something like:

```
var listCE = _context.Ce
                     .Where(x => x.VuId == element.VuId)
                     .Where(x => boolparameter ? x.Score == 8 : true)
                     .AsNoTracking()
                     .ToList();
```

C# Asp.NetCore SqlServer 2019
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Other answers are good but maybe a bit hard to catch. I found this easier to understand. `(boolparameter && x.Score==8) || !boolparameter`. of course if you simplify this it will become like the answers given.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the following code if it works:

```
var listCE = _context.Ce
  .Where(x => x.VuId == element.VuId)
  .Where(x => !boolparameter || x.Score == 8)
  .AsNoTracking()
  .ToList();
```

Which means if `boolparameter` is `false`, x.Score doesn't matter, since `!false` would equal to `true` and it satisfies OR condition. Likewise if `boolparameter` is `true`, then `x.score` will also be checked if it is equal to 8.

Or maybe with one Where condition:

```
var listCE = _context.Ce
  .Where(x => x.VuId == element.VuId && (!boolparameter || x.Score == 8))
  .AsNoTracking()
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var listCE = _context.Ce
    .Where(x =>
        x.VuId == element.VuId
        && (!boolparameter || x.Score == 8))
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
```

This checks whether `boolparameter` is true before checking `x.Score`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check that below?

```
var listCE = _context.Ce
        .Where(x => boolparameter == false ? x.VuId == element.VuId : 
        (x.VuId == element.VuId && 
        x.Score == 8)) 
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This way is more verbose, but if you have more (or complicated) conditions it can be easier to read and quickly understand what affects the query.
LINQ doesn't execute the query until you reach `.ToList()` or otherwise try to access the result from the query.

This means you don't need to have the full query duplicated in both the if and else part:

```
var _context = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<VMContext>();

var listCEQuery = _context.Ce.Where(x => x.VuId == element.VuId)

// LINQ will append this to the initial where clause   
if (boolparameter == true)
    listCEQuery = listCEQuery.Where(x => x.Score == 8)

var listCE = listCEQuery.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```